# Image in a divs affects external divs

Tags: html, css, web

Right now Im trying to put an image on the top of a div. The divs are in horizontal, and I don´t know why, but when I put the image its position affects all external divs... I mean, the image should only affect the div in which I put it.

I know this can be a little bit difficult to undestand, I took a capture of my divs: [Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnavI.png). As you can see, the height of my image affects the external divs.

Here is the HTML code:

```
     <div class="hoteles">
        <div class="head-hoteles">Los mejores hoteles</div>
        <div class="hotel"><img src="images/hotels/hotel-bellevue.jpg" alt="Hotel Bellevue"></div>
        <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
        <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
        <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
        <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
     </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.hoteles{
 background-color: pink; 
 height: 100%; 
 width: 65%; 
 float: left; 
 padding-left: 2%; 
 }

.head-hoteles{
width: 100%; 
height: 100px; 
background-color: yellow; 
padding: 5%; 
font-size: 1.5em; 
}

.hotel{
height: 12.5em; 
min-width: 23%; 
display: inline-block;
background-color: brown; 
margin-bottom: 2%; 
}

.hotel img{   
width: 100px; 
}
```

Other question is... when I put "width 100%" its does not do it, I just can resize the image with pixels... Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `float` the divs, currently your divs are positioned as `inline-block` which is causing disorder. Additionally you can use `vertical-align: top` to order the `inline-block`.

Working example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aodhnh1/)

```css
.hoteles {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
.head-hoteles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.hotel {
    height: 12.5em;
    min-width: 23%;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
    margin:2% 5px 2% 0;
}
.hotel img {
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoteles">
    <div class="head-hoteles">Los mejores hoteles</div>
    <div class="hotel">
        <img src="images/hotels/hotel-bellevue.jpg" alt="Hotel Bellevue" />
    </div>
    <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
    <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
    <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
    <div class="hotel">Hotel1</div>
</div>
```

As for your second question, you need to have a width for the parent of img. Currently it uses min-width, change it to width and give your img the width of 100% and it will expand to the percentage of the parent. Like the following:

```
.hotel {
   width: 23%;
}
.hotel img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following CSS rule:

```
 .hotel { vertical-align: top; }
```

You are seeing the result of inline elements being positioned along the baseline.